# Seg fault during fgets?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

Here's my code:

```
    while (fgets(line, 1000, fp) != NULL) 
    { 
      printf("backin!");
      if ((result = strtok(line,delims)) == NULL)
        printf("Need from_id, to_id, and distance on each line of input file.\n");
      else
        from_id = atoi(result);
      printf("check!\n");
      if ((result = strtok(NULL,delims)) == NULL)
        printf("Need from_id, to_id, and distance on each line of input file.\n");
      else
        to_id = atoi(result);
      printf("check!\n");
      if ((result = strtok(NULL,delims)) == NULL)
        printf("Need from_id, to_id, and distance on each line of input file.\n");
      else
        distance = atof(result);
      printf("check!\n");
      printf("from_id: %d, to_id: %d, distance: %f",from_id, to_id, distance);
      if(BuildGraph(graph_array, from_id, to_id, distance) == -1)
        printf("Error while filling in graph type"); 
      printf("check!\n");
    }
```

All those printfs are just to locate where the segfault takes place.  The input file is 100 lines long, and this function works 15 times, completes all the checks, and then seg faults before "backin!" is printed on the 16th iteration.

I looked through the input file and there's nothing fishy about it (definitely fewer than 1000 characters), seems like there's just an issue with fgets but I don't know what.

Comment: go through questions you asked previously and accept whatever you consider were good answers

Comment: How is `line` defined? is it large enough to hold 1000 chars?

Comment: wow that was it.  Line holds 21 chars, this line looks like 21 but i guess it was 22 for some reason.  Changed it to 30 and it works.  thanks.  Btw can I accept this answer somehow?

Comment: No, that was a comment, not an answer. If @MichaelSh adds an answer then you can accept that ... did you change line to hold 30 chars but still try to read 1000? That would defeat the purpose of the length argument to fgets.

Comment: I'm curious - what did you think the meaning of the `1000` argument was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the size of `line` is at least 1000 chars or change your code as:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) 
...
```

You need to have your `line` large enough to hold the longest line or have a logic to process partial lines.

Comment: +1: That's usually the right way to do it (using `sizeof(line)`), unless the buffer is passed as an argument to the function that calls `fgets()`.  Then you need arguments such as `char *buffer, size_t buflen` to tell you how big the buffer is, and you call `fgets(buffer, buflen, fp)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using fscanf with the help of regular expression `"%[^\n]s"`. this will accept all your tokens till end of line character.

- Irrelavant to the question but still, practice using getch() after printf.